# How do I associate a file with a perspective in an eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, file, plugins, associations, perspective

I have created an editor plug-in for eclipse that is associated with the file extension .eap

I have also created a perspective that contains views for this data.

I would like to add the following behaviour:  When I double click on the .eap file I'd like the EAP Perspective to be opened.

Just like what happens when you click on a Java file for the first time.

Any help appreciated!

Will

---

```
    try {
        IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
        workbench.showPerspective(EapPerspective.ID,
                workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow());
    } catch (WorkbenchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, clicking on or opening a Java file for the first time will not open the Java perspective.  However, perhaps you are thinking about how after using the New Java Class Wizard, you are prompted to change to the Java perspective.

Regardless, there are several things that you can do:

- In the org.eclipse.ui.newWizards extension point, specify the finalPerspective as well as preferredPerspectives
- Assuming that you have sub-classed `AbstractTextEditor`, then override the `setFocus()` method and add some logic to change to the appropriate perspective, something like this (but be careful to add specific null checks):

  getEditorSite().getWorkbenchWindow().getWorkbench().showPerspective(desc.getId(),
                  getWindow(), pageInput);

The first solution is recommended, although it will not cover all the cases that you are asking for, and the second is a bit naughty as it goes against Eclipse conventions.

Comment: I went the second route.  I've in-lined the code to swtich perspectives for future use.  You're right too, it's the new project wizard that tries to switch you to a perspective!